# Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту

Tags: обсуждение, реклама

Вы могли заметить, что на основном сайте в боковой панели появились баннеры, которые призывают пользователей задавать вопросы (при клике осуществляется переход на страницу публикации вопроса). В будущем мы планируем показывать их только неавторизованным пользователям, дабы уменьшить информационный шум постоянным участникам сообщества.

Дизайнеры компании предложили несколько альтернативных вариантов арта для баннеров, один из которых спешу обсудить с вами!

[image: img]

<sub>На изображении [@Korneel Bouman](http://stackexchange.com/users/77247/korneel-bouman) один из сотрудников Stack Overflow.</sub>

Мне кажется, было бы здорово подготовить ряд баннеров с изображением профиля реальных участников Stack Overflow на русском и их личным приглашением задавать вопросы. Почему? Stack Overflow, по сути, - это две важнейшие составляющие:

- сообщество профессиональных разработчиков;
- свободная база прикладных решений.

И, как мне кажется, именно сообщество идет на первом месте. Stack Overflow всегда будет состоять из энтузиастов, которым небезразлична профессия и судьба их коллег. На мой взгляд, ключевым фактором при принятии решения, быть частью сообщества или нет, являются лидеры Stack Overflow. Их знания, открытость и личный пример побуждают начать обмен профессиональным опытом (зарегистрироваться и задать вопрос или опубликовать ответ), а значит и повысить свою квалификацию!

### Почему изображения участников?

Я много раз присутствовал на различных конференциях с рассказом про Stack Overflow. Много раз я слышал скептические неподкрепленные обоснованиями фразы вида «Stack Overflow на русском – нонсенс!». Самое действенное решение – предложить посетить [страницу участников сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users) и обратить внимание на ответы и вопросы ребят и девушек. После этого абсурдность любых подобных фраз становится видна абсолютно каждому.

### Чуть-чуть деталей

#### Каковы условия участия?

1. Истинное желание помогать коллегам.
2. Более 50 ответов.
3. Репутация более 1 000 баллов.

#### Какие требования к слогану?

1. Оригинальность.
2. Действие, к которому мы побуждаем, – публикация вопроса.
3. Слоган не должен быть длинным. Оптимально – до 60 символов.

#### Как, предположительно, будет выглядеть баннер?

Баннер будет состоять из трех основных частей.

1. Фоновое изображение из профиля участника.
2. Личный призыв участника задавать вопросы на сайте (слоган).
3. Имя пользователя, под слоганом.
4. Изображение кнопки с надписью «задать вопрос» (призыв к действию).

Также смотрите шаблон в начале этого вопроса.

#### Где будет отображаться баннер?

Баннер будет отображаться в боковой панели (и, с малой вероятностью, под заголовком вопроса, после первого ответа) на двух сайтах:

- Stack Overflow на английском;
- Stack Overflow на русском.

#### Что необходимо, чтобы принять участие?

Для того чтобы я мог подготовить баннер с вашим изображением, пожалуйста, опубликуйте ответ к этому вопросу, в котором укажите один или несколько слоганов, которые вы бы хотели видеть на баннере с вашим изображением.

#### Сколько баннеров попадут в ранжирование?

Предлагаю начать с восьми баннеров. Критерии отбора (по убыванию важности):

- репутация участника;
- оригинальность слогана;
- суммарное количество ответов автора;
- время публикации ответа (от более ранних к более поздним).

Если у вас есть какие-либо предложения или замечания, пожалуйста, опубликуйте их в *комментариях* к этому вопросу.

**Давайте вместе  поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту!**

### Обновление: первые изображения

Мы получили первый вариант баннеров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кстати, по слогану, тут на мете вроде задавался вопрос про то что он не совсем точен: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2467/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-ru-so

Comment: Интересная идея, и что также интересно, на английском сайте я ничего такого не читал. Т.е. эксперимент начинается с русского сайта?  Кстати, есть опечатка: [задайть вопрос](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0yL09.png).

Comment: мне кажется, татуировку на руке лучше бы «замазать». просто чтобы не гадать, какого эффекта (нейтрального, положительного, отрицательного) она произведёт больше.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я думаю, цель показать настоящих людей, а не фотомоделей.

Comment: @Etki, я думаю, что единственная цель размещения фотографии – вызвать эмоциональный отклик (никакой информационной нагрузки она не несёт). скорее всего – положительный. вот потому я и написал предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  Мне кажется, формулировка `Фоновое изображение из профиля участника` неверна. Насколько я понял из обсуждения, говорится о фото, а на аватарке может быть что угодно...

Comment: @VenZell Имелось в виду именно аватар участника.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо за уточнение, но я плохо представляю аватарку вроде моей на подобном баннере. Она не вызовет эмоционального отклика, в отличие от фото

Comment: @VenZell Да, соглашусь, думал об этом. Причина проста – далеко не каждый захочет выходить за рамки своего «сетевого Я», что вполне справедливо. Участник сам выбирает свое изображение на сайте, именно с этим изображением происходит ассоциация. Как результат, со стороны знатока, на мой взгляд, вполне логично использовать именно изображение из учётной записи.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, Идея крутая, но я тут вижу два осложнения: 1) юзерпики не настолько хайрезны, чтобы натянуть их на баннер предполагаемого размера, 2) при использовании юзерпика или даже фотографии присланной пользователем (не профессиональной, снятой именно с этой целью) сильно пострадает дизайнерская составляющая.

Comment: @Nofate Баннер небольшого размера (300х250). При регистрации на gravatar, запрашивается крупное изображение, сам сервис отдает его в запрашиваемом размере. На сколько плохо все будет, можно будет судить лишь после первых откликов. Уверен, дизайнеры что-нибудь придумают!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, я это просто к тому что, специально сделанное фото, как в посте, смотрелось бы профессиональнее (речь не о профессионализме человека на фото, а о подходе в целом). Хотя да, желающих наверное поуменьшилось бы.

Comment: Я не буду помогать потому, что банеры - зло. Любые банеры.

Comment: @Nofate [Ваш аватар в размере 300 по ширине](https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3faf43a8013b65785618445d0b2d8b07?s=300&d=identicon&r=PG)... с разрешением нет проблем, правда немного страшноват...

Comment: @Sally, но я могу и живьем, как-то так: http://gloimg.gearbest.com/gb/2015/201509/source-img/1442166577479-P-3103937.jpg

Comment: @Nofate, это фото определенно сподвигнет задать вопрос :)))

Comment: А что, будут баннеры-то? :)

Comment: @andreycha Да, конечно! [В пятницу подготовил финальную табличку](http://goo.gl/Ro8cDp) и отправил на реализацию.

Comment: @andreycha Обновил публикацию.

Comment: HANG ON. "В оригинале" моего "слогана" знака вопроса не было, потому что там не было вопроса. Это "алгоритм моих действий на ruSO". Я ищу вопрос, на который не знаю ответа, и узнаю его.

Comment: @D-side готово, поправил!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо! Впредь, пожалуйста, спрашивайте о подобных изменениях, возможно, намерения автора были просто неверно поняты :)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky по-моему, у меня и avp самые отпугивающие баннеры вышли :). Как вариант, текст про дурака можно изменить на более мягкое "Не стыдись спросить -- не знать еще постыднее" (японская пословица). Плюс меня не отпускают сомнения, что в исходном тексте есть проблемы с пунктуацией.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и в "Не нашли решение, задайте ваш вопрос!" должна быть не запятая, а знак вопроса.

Comment: @andreycha Обновил публикацию!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а почему оранжевые? вроде ж цвета ruSO - синие?

Comment: @Grundy К сожалению, не смогу ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо.

Comment: @Grundy кроме маленького синего значка больше ничего нет. На всем остальнам сайте постоянно встречается оранжевый -- как-никак фирменный для SO.

Comment: @andreycha, возможно цвет чата запутал.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky  "Самый глупый вопрос - не заданный.

Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа." Это как бы два слогана. Хорошо бы развести их отдельно :)

Comment: Обновил арт баннеров.

Comment: Выскажу мнение чатика: цветовая гамма баннеров режет глаз.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я бы облачко немного сместил относительно аватара вправо.

Comment: @D-side Обновил баннер. Надеюсь, сейчас все верно :)

Comment: Синий и оранжевый плохо сочитаются имхо. Вырвиглазно получается.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов Я не дизайнер, судить не могу. Очень надеюсь, что на этой неделе до воскресенья у меня получится разместить и мы сможем увидеть реакцию сообщества.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я уже опоздал, или сюда залезть ещё можно?

Comment: @Squidward Пока, как мне кажется, мы будем работать с уже созданными изображениями.

Comment: Не в первый раз уже взгляд цепляется за двусмысленный слоган "Фантомный баг не дает уснуть? Ищи его на SO". Первое, что приходит в голову - СО это сборище багов? Или - если у меня фантомный баг, значит виноват СО? Или же - на СО можно прийти и просто сказать "ничего не работает", а тебе тут же расскажут, откуда этот "подземный стук" происходит и за тебя всё решат? Можно и дальше продолжать :) Нет, я понимаю, что хотел сказать автор слогана. Но для этого приходится немного поворочать мозгами, мысля исключительно в позитивном ключе.

Answer (score 24):

Простите, не удержался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: очень даже в тему, только если будут фото сотрудников СТАК с позитивом, то ресурс только выиграет ! только незабывать чередовать, с юмором и серъезный.

Answer (score 13):

> Самый глупый вопрос - не заданный.
>
> Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа

Comment: Еще  из той же оперы -- "не бывает глупых вопросов, бывают только глупые ответы".

Comment: @avp Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ваш вариант отдельным ответом!

Comment: _Правильно заданный вопрос - половина ответа,_ а неправильно - куча магии в ответах. Это было про [случай с обобщением вопроса](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/521273/178988), но понял, что это [ещё одной идее](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519849/178988) соответствует.

Answer (score 12):

С такими ограничениями на длину слоганов напрашивается формат [хайку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83).

```
Находишь занятный вопрос,
На который не знаешь ответа.
Узнавая - изучишь.
```

По мотивам [моего единственного (на данный момент) ответа на Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299848/how-do-i-find-questions-that-are-more-my-level/299856#299856), принесшего мне значок "Гуру". Забавно вышло.

Примерно так я на StackOverflow и обитаю: можно заметить, что на ruSO вопросов у меня **нет вообще**, а на SO вопрос **один** (на самом деле два, один я стёр за бесполезностью). Возможно, этот слоган подходит с обратной стороны, он мотивирует скорее не задавать вопросы, а отвечать; вопрошающих он мотивировать тоже может, но косвенно.

---

```
NullPointerException
И полный путями стектрейс
Не в первый же раз?
```

Этот с радостью готов отдать любому желающему, поскольку он слабо стыкуется с направленностью моего вклада в сообщество (я на самом деле сильно не люблю Java, мне просто понравился ритм названия).

Answer (score 10):

> Сомневаетесь, задавать ли вопрос?
>
> Не бойтесь, не бывает глупых вопросов, бывают только глупые ответы.

Comment: Спасибо! Здорово!

Answer (score 10):

> Лучше спросить и побыть дураком пять минут,
>   чем промолчать и остаться им на всю жизнь!
>
> Задать вопрос >>

Answer (score 8):

Вариант 1

```
Фантомный баг не даёт уснуть?
Ищи его на StackOverflow
```

Вариант 2

```
Опять Exception'ы?
StackOverflow много их повидал.
Спроси его, он знает ответ.
```

Comment: Особенно NPE. C ними каждый первый сюда бежит :)

Answer (score 8):

Незнание - тьма, учение - свет. Не задав вопроса, не получишь ответ!

Comment: "же" сносит рифму к чертям :-), кроме того, можно вернуть "и" в ученье, вместо "ь", читаться вслух все равно будет в рифму

Comment: да, "же", наверное, лучше убрать) я ударение в слове "задав" неправильно поставила, когда писала))

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку, как мне кажется, я могу чем-то помочь по C++, предлагаю следующий слоган.

> Ищешь ответ по C++?
>   Помогу советом на Stack Overflow!

Либо без «советом», `Помогу на Stack Overflow!`. Ниже кнопка,

> Задать вопрос >>