# Реклама сообщества

Tags: поддержка, faq

Шаг за шагом Stack Overflow становится популярнее среди русскоязычных разработчиков.

- Stack Overflow на английском 4.5М сессий за февраль этого года с установленным русским языком в обозревателе (3.7М в прошлом году).
- Stack Overflow на русском 1.2М сессий за февраль этого года (0.7М в прошлом году).

На данный момент, Stack Overflow на русском является полностью некоммерческой инициативой компании. Как результат, на сайте нет рекламных объявлений (за исключением [недавней инициативы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/)). Как мне кажется, было бы здорово как-то с пользой для сообщества расходовать место на сайте, учитывая, что объявления показываются только участникам с репутацией менее 200 баллов, и более 90% всех посещений идут из поисковиков.

Впервые идея размещения на сайте объявлений от участников сообщества была [анонсирована](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/) [Джефом Этвудом](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) в конце 2009 года.

Предоставление мест для размещения рекламы от сообщества призвано помочь привлечь внимание к проектам с открытым кодом и другим полезным активностям участников за счет использования невостребованных показов страниц.

Для того чтобы реклама попала на сайт, необходимо следующее:

1. В отведенное время в специальном вопросе на Мета Stack Overflow на русском опубликовать ответ (вопрос должен быть отмечен меткой [реклама-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0)).
2. Подготовить и добавить в ответ изображение для рекламного объявления проекта  с исходным кодом, которым вы хотите поделиться с сообществом, размером 300 на 250 пикселов. Изображение обязательно должно соответствовать требованиям размера.
3. Для того чтобы объявление попало в ротацию, соответствующий ответ должен набрать заданное пороговое значение голосов «за».
4. После этого ваше объявление появится в боковой панели Stack Overflow на русском.

Другими словами, объявление напрямую из вопроса на Мете

[img http://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stack-overflow-open-source-ad-answer.png](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stack-overflow-open-source-ad-answer.png)

Попадает в боковую панель, которую видят все ваши коллеги.

[img2 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stack-overflow-open-source-ad-live.png](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stack-overflow-open-source-ad-live.png)

На наш взгляд, подобная инициатива поможет развитию многих проектов с открытым кодом и ИТ–индустрии в целом.

Поскольку все рекламные объявления полностью создаются сообществом, мы оставляем за собой право не размещать те объявления, которые считаем неуместными или нежелательными для сайта.

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на описание метки [реклама-сообщества](/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0). Также, вам может быть интересна публикация «[Community Promotion Ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)».

Comment: Можно ли таким образом рекламировать встречи-конференции? И если да, то есть ли для них какие-то условия(бесплатный вход-темы про опенсорс и т.д.)?

Comment: Еще один странный вопрос, Можно ли рекламировать другие сайты сети stackexchange? Например если будет какое-то еще сообщество на русском?

Comment: @Vartlok про встречи-конференции тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2611/

Comment: @Vartlok Да, конечно, можно предложить объявление о другом сообществе!