# Почему мне все время видна реклама с цитатами участников ruSO?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, реклама

Например, вот:
[image: реклама от гуглА]

Почему мне видна эта реклама? У меня две версии: на SO продают рекламу, и из-за того что я часто сижу на SO, мне показывается реклама SO. Но зачем мне эта реклама, если я уже на SO, я же не буду на нее кликать? Либо это специальный баннер от создателей SO для новичков(хотя реклама вроде гугловская), т.к. я не видел другой рекламы. Но тогда опять же какой от нее прок, если я уже на SO и знаю как задавать вопросы?(клик ведет на форму задания вопроса)

Comment: см. вопрос [Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/1984)

Comment: @Nofate ааа, понял. Да, я тогда незалогиненый был.